# Optimise python functions for speed

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, memory-optimization

Any one can help me optimise those three functions? I did profiling and timing of my original python file and found that most calls and time duration was because of those three functions.

The three functions are from a text normaliser for text processing. The full python file is available if anyone wants to have a look at the whole script. Thank you

```
   def __rstrip(self, token):
        for i in range(5):
            if len(token):
                if token[-1] in [',', '.', ';', '!', '?', ':', '"']:
                    token = token[:-1]
                else:
                    break
        return token

    def __lstrip(self, token):
        for i in range(5):
            if len(token):
                if token[0] in [',', '.', ';', '!', '?', ':', '"', '\'']:
                    token = token[1:]
                else:
                    break
        return token


    def __generate_results(self, original, normalised):
        words = []
        for t in normalised:
            if len(t[0]):
                words.append(t[0])
        text = ' '.join(words)

        tokens = []
        if len(original):
            for t in original:
                idx = t[1]
                words = []
                for t2 in normalised:
                    if idx == t2[1]:
                        words.append(t2[0])
                display_text = self.__rstrip(t[0])
                display_text = self.__lstrip(display_text)
                tokens.append((t[0], words, display_text))
        else:
            tokens.append(('', '', ''))

        return text, tokens
```

Comment: Would you mind giving a little more detail concerning the `__lstrip` and `__rstrip` functions? Is the goal of these function to remove the first/last 5 symbols of a token? Because it seems like a weird use case.

Comment: You need to provide more information about the data structures. For example, how many elements are typically in a `token`? If these sequences are large, your current stripping methods could be quite inefficient (you create a new list with each iteration); but if they are tiny, that might not be a major issue. Or, how large is `normalised` and what type of collection is it? If it's a large list/tuple, repeated `in` checks might be costly, but if it's small or if it's a dict/set, then perhaps that's not the source of trouble. Currently, your question is too abstract.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some suggestions for general code cleanup. I can't guarantee that any of these changes will improve performance.

---

> ```
> if len(xxx):
> ```

Almost certainly you can replace these with `if xxx:`. It's not guaranteed to be the same, but almost all types that support `len` will test false if their length is 0. This includes strings, lists, dicts, and other standard Python types.

---

I would turn `__rstrip` and `__lstrip` into top-level functions, or at least make them `@staticmethod`s since they don't use `self`. `__generate_results` could be a static method as well.

---

`__rstrip` and `__lstrip` seem to reimplement the functionality of the built-in `str.rstrip` and `str.lstrip`. Possibly, you could replace them with

```
display_text = t[0].rstrip(',.;!?:"')
display_text = display_text.lstrip(',.;!?:"\'')
```

If it's really important that at most 5 characters be stripped, you can do that like this:

```
def _rstrip(token):
    return token[:-5] + token[-5:].rstrip(',.;!?:"')

def _lstrip(token):
    return token[:5].lstrip(',.;!?:"\'') + token[5:]
```

---

> ```
> token[-1] in [',', '.', ';', '!', '?', ':', '"']
> ```

Either `token[-1] in {',', '.', ';', '!', '?', ':', '"'}` or `token[-1] in ',.;!?:"'` would be faster. The latter is riskier since it's not exactly the same: it will do a substring test if `token[-1]` isn't a single character. But if `token` is a string then `token[-1]` is guaranteed to be a single character.

---

> ```
> words = []
> for t in normalised:
>     if len(t[0]):
>         words.append(t[0])
> ```

You can replace this with `words = [t[0] for t in normalised if t[0]]`.

---

> ```
>  words = []
>  for t2 in normalised:
>      if idx == t2[1]:
>          words.append(t2[0])
> ```

This *could* be a significant source of inefficiency. You could try making a lookup table outside the loop:

```
normalized_lookup = collections.defaultdict(list)
for t in normalized:
    normalized_lookup[t[1]].append(t[0])
```

and then replace the quoted code with `words = normalized_lookup[idx]`. This could end up being slower, though. Also, it has the side effect that lists for the same value of `idx` will be shared, which could cause subtle, hard-to-catch aliasing bugs down the line. If that's an issue, write `words = list(normalized_lookup[idx])` (or `tuple`).